# How to run a powershell script from a win form written in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

first of all, I've got a bit of development skills but it's been ages since i've use them.
Now i'm trying to automate an install for a server application.
So what i'm trying to do here, and I've been googling for a while now,
is to open a Powershell script (that I already created, and added to the project.
I've added all the code so you can see where I'm going wrong.
Once the script is done I need the if () to show me if it's been completed correct or not.

here is the code:

```
 using System; 
 using System.Collections.Generic; 
 using System.ComponentModel; 
 using System.Data; 
 using System.Drawing; 
 using System.Linq; 
 using System.Text; 
 using System.Threading.Tasks; 
 using System.Collections.ObjectModel; 
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {

 public partial class Form3 : Form
 {
     public Form3()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     //here i want to launch the powershell script
 private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if ( )
         {

         }
         else {
             MessageBox.Show("There is an error in the application or data", "Prerequisite",
             MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                 Application.Exit();
              }
     }

 } }
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Comment: if your ps script on file, or you hard code it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use "PowerShellInstance.Invoke();"

Microsoft has a great tutorial here. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Comment: I noticed that your are not "using system.management.automation".

Comment: i've found that, but i still can't get the powershell to work. i have the using in there

Answer (score 1):

Add Reference : **System.Management.Automation**

Using **System.Collections.Objectmodel** and 
using **System.Management.Automation**

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
                // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript("param($urlPath) New-Item -ItemType directory -Path \"$urlPath$d\";");

                // use "AddParameter" to add a single parameter to the last command/script on the pipeline.
                PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("urlPath", @"D:\New PS Folder\");
                Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

                // loop through each output object item
                foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
                {
                    // if null object was dumped to the pipeline during the script then a null
                    // object may be present here. check for null to prevent potential NRE.
                    if (outputItem != null)
                    {
                        //TODO: do something with the output item 
                        // outputItem.BaseOBject
                        MessageBox.Show(outputItem.Properties.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: so i've added and changed some things. Some are working, some aren't. I'm going to close this thread as the question i've asked is working